# MongoDB aggregation $group step sum arrays by index

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a step in my aggregation pipeline where I have documents that look like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5943f427e7c11ac3ad3652b2",
    "brand": 1,
    "date": [
      "2017-06-10T00:00:00.000Z",
      "2017-06-11T00:00:00.000Z",
      "2017-06-12T00:00:00.000Z",
      "2017-06-13T00:00:00.000Z",
      "2017-06-14T00:00:00.000Z",
      "2017-06-15T00:00:00.000Z",
      "2017-06-16T00:00:00.000Z"
    ],
    "stat": [0, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 7]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5943f427e7c11ac3ad3652b3",
    "brand": 1,
    "date": [
      "2017-06-10T00:00:00.000Z",
      "2017-06-11T00:00:00.000Z",
      "2017-06-12T00:00:00.000Z",
      "2017-06-13T00:00:00.000Z",
      "2017-06-14T00:00:00.000Z",
      "2017-06-15T00:00:00.000Z",
      "2017-06-16T00:00:00.000Z"
    ],
    "stat": [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
  }
]
```

And what I would like to do is sum my `stat` objects by index of the array.
i.e.I I want to add all the 0th elements, all 1st elements ... all the 7th elements.

So I would like to end up with:

```
{
    "_id": "5943f427e7c11ac3ad3652b3",
    "brand": 1,
    "date": [
      "2017-06-10T00:00:00.000Z",
      "2017-06-11T00:00:00.000Z",
      "2017-06-12T00:00:00.000Z",
      "2017-06-13T00:00:00.000Z",
      "2017-06-14T00:00:00.000Z",
      "2017-06-15T00:00:00.000Z",
      "2017-06-16T00:00:00.000Z"
    ],
    "stat": [1, 4, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12]
}
```

Getting the date array is fine as I can just use $first during the `$group` on `brand`, But I can't figure out a way to do an index-wise sum on `stat` inside a `$group` step.

Any ideas?!

Comment: Honestly I would be rather questioning the aggregation stages used to obtain this result. If you have two separate arrays that actually relate, then the most simple solution would be to apply the previous steps in such a way that the elements are not in separate arrays as shown here. If they can get into a related state like this, then logically the previous data states can already produce your "merged" result. You should in fact show *"how you got here"* and fix that process instead. But that may indeed be a separate question.

Comment: In fact I would go [dollars to doughnuts](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/dollars-to-donuts.html) that in fact you actually have the prior form of `[{ "date": "2017-06-10T00:00:00.000Z", "stat": 0 }, { "date": "2017-06-11T00:00:00.000Z", "stat": 2}]` and even more likely that none of that was even originally inside an array. To which end, correcting the steps beforehand alleviates the problem. Rather than trying to deal with this present state.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have that prior form. I do agree though that the aggregation pipeline is getting too convoluted now. I will look to see if I can alter the steps beforehand to get data into a more `$group`able form. Thank you for the advice around the question

Comment: If you have a "convoluted pipeline" then I would strongly suggest you [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) showing the full pipeline and ideally a small source of documents to work with, so that then it is possible to advise you on how to do this "better" to get to the end format. In fact, the end format may be questionable since I could speculate that you want these arrays for a charting package, and most I know of actually accept different output formats. Nonetheless it "should" be a new question as opposed to altering this one, especially once an answer exists.

Comment: I agree. You're right - the data is to be ingested by charts.js on the client. Their ingested data format seems to just be arrays for each axis.

Comment: charts.js does in fact accept different formats AFAIK. Ask the question like I suggested.

Comment: Made a new question here. Thanks for your advice so far: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627730/querying-mongodb-for-some-chart-data-my-pipeline-seems-convoluted

Answer (score 2):

You can try below aggregation in 3.4 pipeline.

Currently `$group` stage doesn't provide access to previous values. More [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29161)

You can `$push` `stat` arrays in `$group` stage followed with `$zip`ing  the current and previous `stat` array and compute `$sum` for each zipped array element inside `$map` stage to output array of summed values and `$reduce` to compute the output summed array values for `stat` in a `$addFields` stage.

Use `useLongestLength` attribute for `$zip` operator as the initial `$$value` is empty array.

```
aggregate(
    [{
            $group: {
                _id: "$brand",
                date: {
                    $first: "$date"
                },
                stat: {
                    $push: "$stat"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $addFields: {
                stat: {
                    $reduce: {
                        input: "$stat",
                        initialValue: [],
                        in: {
                            $map: {
                                input: {
                                    $zip: {
                                        inputs: ["$$this", "$$value"],
                                        useLongestLength: true
                                    }
                                },
                                as: "result",
                                in: {
                                    $sum: "$$result"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

There is open ticket [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29339) to allow `$reduce` operator in `$group` stage. You can then move the `$reduce` logic to `$group`.

Comment: I agree that you can do this with MongoDB 3.4 operators, and I think it's relatively possible as well in earlier versions and probably most simple with 3.2 operators. I do question however that for the data to get into it's present state as "a result of aggregation" that it would be necessary to do this at all, considering that it is likely the result can be obtained by correcting the earlier pipeline stages not shown. Nonetheless, points of correct approach to the problem given. But also really should have questioned the OP about how they obtained the data in the state in the first place.