# Querying mongoDB for some chart data - my pipeline seems convoluted

Tags: mongodb, charts, aggregation-framework, chart.js

This is a long question. If you bother answering, I will be extra grateful.

I have some time series data that I am trying to query to create various charts. The data format isn't the most simple, but I think my aggregation pipeline is getting a bit out of hand. I am planning to use **charts.js** to visualise the data on the client.

I will post a sample of my data below as well as my pipeline, with the desired output.

My question is in two parts - answering either one could solve the problem.

1. Does charts.js accept data formats other than an array of numbers per row? This would mean my pipeline could try to do less.
2. My pipeline doesn't quite get to the result I need. **Can you recommend any alterations to get the correct result from my pipeline?** Is there is a simpler way to get my desired output format?

## Sample data

**Here is a real data sample** - a brand with one facebook account and one twitter account. There is some data for some dates in June. Lots of null day and month fields have been omitted.

#### Brand

```
  [{
    "_id": "5943f427e7c11ac3ad3652b0",
    "name": "Brand1",
    "facebookAccounts": [
      "5943f427e7c11ac3ad3652ac",
    ],
    "twitterAccounts": [
        "5943f427e7c11ac3ad3652aa",
    ],
  }]
```

#### FacebookAccounts

```
[
      {
        "_id" : "5943f427e7c11ac3ad3652ac"
        "name": "Brand 1 Name",
        "years": [
          {
            "date": "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "months": [
              {
                "date": "2017-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                "days": [
                  {
                    "date": "2017-06-16T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "likes": 904025,
                  },
                  {
                    "date": "2017-06-17T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "likes": null,
                  },
                  {
                    "date": "2017-06-18T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "likes": 904345,
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

#### Twitter accounts

```
[
      {
        "_id": "5943f427e7c11ac3ad3652aa",
        "name": "Brand 1 Name",
        "vendorId": "twitterhandle",
        "years": [
          {
            "date": "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "months": [
              {
                "date": "2017-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                "days": [
                  {
                    "date": "2017-06-16T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "followers": 69390,
                  },
                  {
                    "date": "2017-06-17T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "followers": 69397,
                  {
                    "date": "2017-06-18T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "followers": 69428,
                  },
                  {
                    "date": "2017-06-19T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "followers": 69457,
                  },
                ]
              },
            ],
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

---

## The query

For this example, I want, for each brand, a daily sum of facebook likes and twitter followers between June 16th and June 18th. So here, the required format is:

```
{
  brand: Brand1,
  date: ["2017-06-16T00:00:00.000Z", "2017-06-17T00:00:00.000Z", "2017-06-18T00:00:00.000Z"],
  stat: [973415, 69397, 973773]
}
```

---

## The pipeline

The pipeline seems more convoluted due to the population, but I accept that complexity and it is necessary. Here are the steps:

```
db.getCollection('brands').aggregate([
{ $match: { _id: { $in: [ObjectId("5943f427e7c11ac3ad3652b0") ] } } },


// Unwind all relevant account types. Make one row per account
{ $project: { 
    accounts: { $setUnion: [ '$facebookAccounts', '$twitterAccounts' ] } ,
    name: '$name'
    }
 },
{ $unwind: '$accounts' },


// populate the accounts. 
// These transform the arrays of facebookAccount ObjectIds into the objects described above. 
{ $lookup: { from: 'facebookaccounts', localField: 'accounts', foreignField: '_id', as: 'facebookAccounts' } },
{ $lookup: { from: 'twitteraccounts', localField: 'accounts', foreignField: '_id', as: 'twitterAccounts' } },

// unwind the populated accounts. Back to one record per account.
{ $unwind: { path: '$facebookAccounts', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
{ $unwind: { path: '$twitterAccounts', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },


// unwind to the granularity we want. Here it is one record per day per account per brand.
{ $unwind: { path: '$facebookAccounts.years', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
{ $unwind: { path: '$facebookAccounts.years.months', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
{ $unwind: { path: '$facebookAccounts.years.months.days', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
{ $unwind: { path: '$facebookAccounts.years.months.days', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
{ $unwind: { path: '$twitterAccounts.years', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
{ $unwind: { path: '$twitterAccounts.years.months', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
{ $unwind: { path: '$twitterAccounts.years.months.days', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
{ $unwind: { path: '$twitterAccounts.years.months.days', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },


// Filter each one between dates
{ $match: { $or: [
    { $and: [
        { 'facebookAccounts.years.months.days.date': { $gte: new Date('2017-06-16') } } ,
        { 'facebookAccounts.years.months.days.date': { $lte: new Date('2017-06-18') } } 
    ]},
    { $and: [
        { 'twitterAccounts.years.months.days.date': { $gte: new Date('2017-06-16') } } ,
        { 'twitterAccounts.years.months.days.date': { $lte: new Date('2017-06-18') } } 
     ]}
] }},    


// Build stats and date arrays for each account
{ $group: {
    _id: '$accounts',
    brandId: { $first: '$_id' },
    brandName: { $first: '$name' },
    stat: { 
         $push: { 
             $sum: { 
                 $add: [
                    { $ifNull: ['$facebookAccounts.years.months.days.likes', 0] },
                    { $ifNull: ['$twitterAccounts.years.months.days.followers', 0] }
                 ] 
             } 
         } 
     },
     date: { $push: { $ifNull: ['$facebookAccounts.years.months.days.date', '$twitterAccounts.years.months.days.date'] } } ,
}}


])
```

This gives me the output format

```
[{
  _id: accountId, // facebook
  brandName: 'Brand1'
  date: ["2017-06-16T00:00:00.000Z", "2017-06-17T00:00:00.000Z", "2017-06-18T00:00:00.000Z"],
  stat: [904025, null, 904345]
},
{
  _id: accountId // twitter
  brandName: 'Brand1',
  date: ["2017-06-16T00:00:00.000Z", "2017-06-17T00:00:00.000Z", "2017-06-18T00:00:00.000Z"],
  stat: [69457, 69390, 69397]
}]
```

So I now need to perform column-wise addition on my `stat` properties.And then I am stuck - I feel like there should be a more pipeline friendly way to sum these rather than column-wise addition.

**Note** I accept the extra work that the population required and am happy with that. Most of the repetition is done programmatically.

Thank you if you've gotten this far.

Comment: Might need a little more information than that. There are two `$lookup` stages and the related data is not in your question. Also helpful if any paths that are not actually referenced are excluded from this and other sources to keep it relevant and at a reasonable size of post.

Comment: The $lookups just populate the accounts from ObjectIds, resulting in the format that I give in the sample data section - bringing in the object with the years/months/days properties.

Comment: Are we not using that information in the results? If so then why are the `$lookup` stages there in the first place? I'm asking for the "complete" data required to actually output a valid result. And by complete I mean "minimally complete" if it was not clear we do not need to see any data which actually will not be used.

Comment: I've split the sample data now into a format that will work with the aggregation query I have supplied. The two account collections are named `facebookaccounts` and `twitteraccounts` respectively. We do need the `$lookups`, I just wasn't presenting the data in it's true form. I've changed this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can trim a lot of fat out of this and keep it compatible with MongoDB 3.2 ( which you must be using at least due to `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` ) available operators with a few simple actions. Mostly by simply joining the arrays immediately after [`$lookup`,](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) which is the best place to do it:

### Short Optimize

```
db.brands.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "facebookaccounts",
    "localField": "facebookAccounts",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "facebookAccounts"
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "twitteraccounts",
    "localField": "twitterAccounts",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "twitterAccounts"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "all": {
      "$concatArrays": [ "$facebookAccounts", "$twitterAccounts" ]
    }
  }},
  { "$match": {
    "all.years.months.days.date": {
      "$gte": new Date("2017-06-16"), "$lte": new Date("2017-06-18")
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$all" },
  { "$unwind": "$all.years" },
  { "$unwind": "$all.years.months" },
  { "$unwind": "$all.years.months.days" },
  { "$match": {
    "all.years.months.days.date": {
      "$gte": new Date("2017-06-16"), "$lte": new Date("2017-06-18")
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "brand": "$name",
      "date": "$all.years.months.days.date"
    },
    "total": { 
      "$sum": { 
        "$sum": [
          { "$ifNull": [ "$all.years.months.days.likes", 0 ] },
          { "$ifNull": [ "$all.years.months.days.followers", 0 ] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id":  "$_id.brand",
    "date": { "$push": "$_id.date" },
    "stat": { "$push": "$total" }
  }}
])
```

This gives the result:

```
{
        "_id" : "Brand1",
        "date" : [
                ISODate("2017-06-16T00:00:00Z"),
                ISODate("2017-06-17T00:00:00Z"),
                ISODate("2017-06-18T00:00:00Z")
        ],
        "stat" : [
                973415,
                69397,
                973773
        ]
}
```

With MongoDB 3.4 we could probably speed it up a "little" more by filtering the arrays and breaking them down before we eventually [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to make this work across documents, or maybe even not worry about going across documents at all if the "name" from "brands" is unique. The pipeline operations to compact down the arrays "in place" though are quite cumbersome to code, if a "little" better on performance.

You seem to be doing this "per brand" or for a small sample, so it's likely of little consequence.

As for the chartjs data format, I don't seem to be able to get my hands on what I believe is a different data format to the array format here, but again this should have little bearing.

The main point I see addressed is we can easily move away from your previous output that separated the "facebook" and "twitter" data, and simply aggregate by date moving all the data together "before" the arrays are constructed.

That last point then obviates the need for further "convoluted" operations to attempt to "merge" those two documents and the arrays produced.

---

### Alternate Optimize

As an alternate approach where this does in fact not aggregate across documents, then you can essentially do the "filter" on the array in place and then simply sum and reshape the received result in client code.

```
db.brands.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "facebookaccounts",
    "localField": "facebookAccounts",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "facebookAccounts"
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "twitteraccounts",
    "localField": "twitterAccounts",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "twitterAccounts"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "all": {
      "$map": {
        "input": { "$concatArrays": [ "$facebookAccounts", "$twitterAccounts" ] },
        "as": "all",
        "in": {
          "years": {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$$all.years",
              "as": "year",
              "in": {
                "months": {
                  "$map": {
                    "input": "$$year.months",
                    "as": "month",
                    "in": {
                      "days": {
                        "$filter": {
                          "input": "$$month.days",
                          "as": "day",
                          "cond": {
                            "$and": [
                              { "$gte": [ "$$day.date", new Date("2017-06-16") ] },
                              { "$lte": [ "$$day.date", new Date("2017-06-18") ] }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
]).map(doc => {
  doc.all = [].concat.apply([],[].concat.apply([],[].concat.apply([],doc.all.map(d => d.years)).map(d => d.months)).map(d => d.days));
  doc.all = doc.all.reduce((a,b) => {
    if ( a.findIndex( d => d.date.valueOf() == b.date.valueOf() ) != -1 ) {
      a[a.findIndex( d => d.date.valueOf() == b.date.valueOf() )].stat += (b.hasOwnProperty('likes')) ? (b.likes || 0) : (b.followers || 0);
    } else {
      a = a.concat([{ date: b.date, stat: (b.hasOwnProperty('likes')) ? (b.likes || 0) : (b.followers || 0) }]);
    }
    return a;
  },[]);

  doc.date = doc.all.map(d => d.date);
  doc.stat = doc.all.map(d => d.stat);
  delete doc.all;
  return doc;
})
```

This really leaves all the things that "need" to happen on the server, on the server. And it's then a fairly trivial task to "flatten" the array and process to "sum up" and reshape it. This would mean less load on the server, and the data returned is not really that much greater per document.

Gives the same result of course:

```
[
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5943f427e7c11ac3ad3652b0"),
                "name" : "Brand1",
                "date" : [
                        ISODate("2017-06-16T00:00:00Z"),
                        ISODate("2017-06-17T00:00:00Z"),
                        ISODate("2017-06-18T00:00:00Z")
                ],
                "stat" : [
                        973415,
                        69397,
                        973773
                ]
        }
]
```

---

### Committing to the Diet

The biggest problem you really have is with the multiple collections and the heavily nested documents. Neither of these is doing you any favors here and will with larger results cause real performance problems.

The nesting in particular is completely unnecessary as well as not being very maintainable since there are limitations to "update" where you have nested arrays. See the positional `$` operator documentation, as well as many posts about this.

Instead you really want a single collection with all those "days" entries in it. You can always work with that source easily for query as well as aggregation purposes and it should look something like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5948cd5cd6eb0b7d6ac38097"),
        "date" : ISODate("2017-06-16T00:00:00Z"),
        "likes" : 904025,
        "__t" : "Facebook",
        "account" : ObjectId("5943f427e7c11ac3ad3652ac")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5948cd5cd6eb0b7d6ac38098"),
        "date" : ISODate("2017-06-17T00:00:00Z"),
        "likes" : null,
        "__t" : "Facebook",
        "account" : ObjectId("5943f427e7c11ac3ad3652ac")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5948cd5cd6eb0b7d6ac38099"),
        "date" : ISODate("2017-06-18T00:00:00Z"),
        "likes" : 904345,
        "__t" : "Facebook",
        "account" : ObjectId("5943f427e7c11ac3ad3652ac")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5948cd5cd6eb0b7d6ac3809a"),
        "date" : ISODate("2017-06-16T00:00:00Z"),
        "followers" : 69390,
        "__t" : "Twitter",
        "account" : ObjectId("5943f427e7c11ac3ad3652aa")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5948cd5cd6eb0b7d6ac3809b"),
        "date" : ISODate("2017-06-17T00:00:00Z"),
        "followers" : 69397,
        "__t" : "Twitter",
        "account" : ObjectId("5943f427e7c11ac3ad3652aa")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5948cd5cd6eb0b7d6ac3809c"),
        "date" : ISODate("2017-06-18T00:00:00Z"),
        "followers" : 69428,
        "__t" : "Twitter",
        "account" : ObjectId("5943f427e7c11ac3ad3652aa")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5948cd5cd6eb0b7d6ac3809d"),
        "date" : ISODate("2017-06-19T00:00:00Z"),
        "followers" : 69457,
        "__t" : "Twitter",
        "account" : ObjectId("5943f427e7c11ac3ad3652aa")
}
```

Combining those referenced in the brands collection as well:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5943f427e7c11ac3ad3652b0"),
        "name" : "Brand1",
        "accounts" : [
                ObjectId("5943f427e7c11ac3ad3652ac"),
                ObjectId("5943f427e7c11ac3ad3652aa")
        ]
}
```

Then you simply aggregate like this:

```
db.brands.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "social",
    "localField": "accounts",
    "foreignField": "account",
    "as": "accounts"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$accounts" },
  { "$match": {
    "accounts.date": {
      "$gte": new Date("2017-06-16"), "$lte": new Date("2017-06-18")
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "brand": "$name",
      "date": "$accounts.date"
    },
    "stat": {
      "$sum": {
        "$sum": [
          { "$ifNull": [ "$accounts.likes", 0 ] },
          { "$ifNull": [ "$accounts.followers", 0 ] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.brand",
    "date": { "$push": "$_id.date" },
    "stat": { "$push": "$stat" }
  }}
])
```

This is actually the most efficient thing you can do, and it's mostly because of what actually happens on the server. We need to look at the "explain" output to see what happens to the pipeline here:

```
{
    "$lookup" : {
      "from" : "social",
      "as" : "accounts",
      "localField" : "accounts",
      "foreignField" : "account",
        "unwinding" : {
          "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : false
        },
        "matching" : {
           "$and" : [
             {
               "date" : {
                 "$gte" : ISODate("2017-06-16T00:00:00Z")
               }
             },
             {
               "date" : {
                 "$lte" : ISODate("2017-06-18T00:00:00Z")
               }
             }
           ]
        }
    }
}
```

This is what happens when you send `$lookup` -> `$unwind` -> `$match` to the server as the latter two stages are "hoisted" into the `$lookup` itself. This reduces the results in the actual "query" run on the collection to be joined.

Without that sequence, then `$lookup` potentially pulls in "a lot of data" with no constraint, and would break the 16MB BSON limit under most normal loads.

So not only is the process a lot more simple in the altered form, it actually "scales" where the present structure will not. This is something that you seriously should consider.

Comment: This approach is really helpful - thank you. I had tried to perform the `$lookup` on an array of accounts previously, to no avail. I am unfortunately having the same trouble with your example here. Does the `$lookup` work when `facebookAccounts` is an array of ObjectIds?

Comment: I think this ability was added in 3.3.4 https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22881  . I have updated my version of mongodb to 3.4.1 and this now works successfully.

Comment: Thank you as well for the more 'client heavy' approach. I will consider them both.

Comment: @dafyddPrys If you read through carefully it's actually not "client heavy" at all. The point there is if you are in fact not "aggregating across brands" then the remainder of the processing is in fact more effectively and efficiently handled with the client code. The actual "date data" at this point is already stripped down to the required range. Flattening the array and accumulating per day at this point is far more complex with the aggregation pipeline than with the code shown, for very little space saved. I also had not quite finished, as I had more to say about your structure as well.

Comment: @dafyddPrys It doesn't work like that. The design is horribly flawed. Just take a look at all the trouble to query here. Maybe you should be asking some more questions here. But I think you need to digest "why" what I say is actually the best structure first.